# Outlook Message - Disable left mouse click on a hyper-link or prevent Outlook to follow clicked hyper-link

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin

Is there a way to intercept mouse click on a hyper-link within current Outlook Message? What I need is to figure out a way to either intercept LEFT mouse click when user tries to click on a hyper-link or to prevent Outlook to open clicked hyper-link...

I hope this is not too confusing and someone can help me with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.